# What's the preferred way to use SVG images in HTML5/CSS3/Javascript applications?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

The options I know of are `<svg>`, `<object>`, `<embed>`, `<img>`, and `<iframe>`. What are their relative merits and drawbacks? Are there any others?

Comment: You forgot css background images, list images, and the content property.

Comment: @Erik: Have you noticed any performance differences between iframe/embed/object? I've noticed object takes significantly longer time to load in Chrome.

Comment: @bennedich: I haven't done any research on that, but I'd be interested in seeing some measurements/tests for all the different cases (hey, this is where you volunteer to blog about this, right? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<iframe>`, `<embed>` and `<object>` all embed external svg files and they all allow scripting. `<embed>` seems to be more or less the de facto standard. The HTML5 spec says:

- *The iframe element represents a nested browsing context.*
- *The embed element represents an integration point for an external (typically non-HTML) application or interactive content.*
- *The object element can represent an external resource, which, depending on the type of the resource, will either be treated as an image, as a nested browsing context, or as an external resource to be processed by a plugin.*

`<svg>` is for inline svg content only but can contain `<image>` elements with external content.

`<img>` and nested `<image>` elements does NOT allow scripting.

Sources:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-embed-element.html#the-embed-element
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-object-element.html#the-object-element